# iPhone app: play video in small view only

Tags: iphone, ios5, video, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my iPhone App I want to play video in a small view.

Video should start playing automatically, and the buttons for play pause and full screen should be hidden.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this within a uiwebview ? If so those others answers may not be what you want

Comment: @martin you are right. this  works for mpmovieplayercontroller. for web view i don"t know how can I do this?

Comment: As its in a UIWebView I was wondering if you wanted to play the video as part of the HTML that is loaded by the web view, in which case you can embed videos easily using the HTML5 video tag to play inline, specifying the size etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would do is manually set the frame for `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view, and set the control style to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`. Much like this below..

```
....
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];

//this is where you create your `embedded` view size
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

[self.view addSubview:player.view];
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[player prepareToPlay];
player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
player.allowsAirPlay = YES;
player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,320)];
[viewPlayer addSubview:player.view];

    self.moviePlayer = player;//declare MPMoviePlayerController class object globaly for play and push the vedio if you want to add this functionality
```

hope,this help you....
:)